# 'double-conversion/double-conversion.h' file not found, lexical or preprocessor issue

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native

[there is some issue when build React Native for IOS, how to solve this ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMqSf.jpg)

Comment: Please do not post link-only or screenshot-only questions.  Relevant code and error messages should be pasted into the question as text.  This is for a whole bunch of good reasons (search, copy/paste into answers, etc...)